# Latest Swift, compact map by case?

Tags: higher-order-functions, swift5

I'm doing this,

```
let x = results.compactMap {
    if case .person (let P) = $0 { return P }
    else { return nil }
}
```

x is `[Person]` , obviously results is something like

```
enum ResultItem: Decodable {
    case person(Person)
    case cat(Cat)
    case budgie(Budgie)
```

Anyway I'm doing this,

```
let x = results.compactMap {
    if case .person (let P) = $0 { return P }
    else { return nil }
}
```

inevitably someone on here can make me **look like a fool** and show a tighter way to do this in current Swift!

Go for it...

Answer (score 2):

So `results` is an array of ResultItem and the idea is to extract the payloads from only the ones that are Persons?

I don't know if this is "tighter" but I would probably do it with `for case let`:

```
let arr : [ResultItem] = // ...
var persons = [Person]()
for case let .person(p) in arr { persons.append(p) }
```

You might reasonably object: "But I don't want `persons` to be a `var`." Yes, I know how you feel. So sometimes I say this instead (wordier, to be sure):

```
let persons : [Person] = 
    arr.reduce(into: []) {if case let .person(p) = $1 {$0.append(p)}}
```

They are both really ways of saying the same thing: append only if you can extract a Person. Of course *you* are doing that same thing, in a way, but the roundabout `return nil` into a `compactMap` is probably the objectionable part, and the second formulation is arguably a one-liner, so perhaps that's "tighter".

Answer (score 1):

maybe define

```
func person(_ r: ResultItem)->Person? {
    if case .person (let P) = r { return P }
    else { return nil }
}
```

and next compact. at least it is easier to read for me ...

```
let persons = items.compactMap(person)
```

or even better

```
extension ResultItem {
    static func person(_ r: ResultItem)->Person? {
        if case .person (let P) = r { return P }
        else { return nil }
    }
}
```

and

```
let persons = items.compactMap(ResultItem.person)
```